# Generate XML file from Oracle Report Builder using SQL query

Tags: xml, oracle

I am trying to generate XML from Oracle Report Builder using the following SQL query:

```
select DISTINCT
ax.emp_no
,p.full_name
,p.previous_name
,a.creation_date
,a.segment4
,a.segment2 
from people_all ax
,people p
,Person pr
,analysis a
,structures s               
where p.person_id = ax.person_id(+)
and ax.full_name = p.full_name
and p.analysis_id = a.analysis_id 
and p.id_num = s.id_num
and s.id_structure Like 'ORT%'
and a.segment1 = 'الحوادث';
```

When I generate to XML, the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 10.1.2.0.2 -->
<REPORT78>
  <LIST_G_EMP_NO>
  </LIST_G_EMP_NO>
</REPORT78>
```

However if I remove the last line `and a.segment1 = 'الحوادث'` the output is fine and work as expected.  So the problem in this line `and a.segment1 = 'الحوادث'`.

Could you please help me!

Comment: looks like an encoding problem

Comment: I need to know why it does not except filters includes Arabic language letters!

Comment: I copied to query from Oracle Reports Builder to paste it again in Oracle SQLDeveloper.  The word 'الحوادث' showed like this 'ÇáãÍÇßãÇÊ'.  While its looks like 'الحوادث' in Reports Builder.

Comment: I also tried to generate the file to PDF and others but I got wrong output.